# JavaScript sort handler not sorting my table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm using Material-UI v3.9.3 to render a table with some test data from an array. I'm relying heavily on the sample code provided on the Material-UI Example page for the Tables component.

My table will render, however, it will not sort with my default state values for sort parameter and sort direction. As a result, the event handler I have for the clickable table headers won't fire either; they simply display the arrow icon for the direction it "should" be sorting when I click them. My code seems to be pretty close tho the example provided at https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/ . I've combed over the code, and just can't wrap my head around where it's going wrong. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried changing the argument values on the "table_sort" function, as well as completely removing the "stabilizedArray" sorting all together and just passing the raw data to my "get_sorting" function to get it working. It still doesn't resolve the issue.

```
  // Sorts table by descending order based on sort parameter
  sort_desc(a, b, sortBy) {
    if (b[sortBy] < a[sortBy]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (b[sortBy] > a[sortBy]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  // Sets sort direction to ascending or descending **WIP** doesn't work
  get_sorting(sort_dir, sort_by) {
    return sort_dir === "desc"
      ? (a, b) => this.sort_desc(a, b, sort_by)
      : (a, b) => -this.sort_desc(a, b, sort_by);
  }

  // Sets up the sorting for the table based on column.
  table_sort(array, get_sorting) {
    const stabilizedArray = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);

    stabilizedArray.sort((a, b) => {
      const order = get_sorting(a[0], b[0]);
      if (order !== 0) return order;
      return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedArray.map(el => el[0]);
  }

  handle_request_sort(e, property) {
    const sort_by = property;
    let sort_dir = "desc";

    if (this.state.sort_by === property && this.state.sort_dir === "desc") {
      sort_dir = "asc";
    }

    this.setState({ sort_dir, sort_by });
  }

  // Renders sorted rows for the table body. Currently renders, but doesn't sort
  row_render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.table_sort(
          testData,
          this.get_sorting(this.state.sort_dir, this.state.sort_by)
        )
          .slice(
            this.state.page * this.state.rowsPerPage,
            this.state.page * this.state.rowsPerPage + this.state.rowsPerPage
          )
          .map(row => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell>
                  <Checkbox />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.order_num}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.sku}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{row.order_date}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Comment: please post on the relevant parts of your question, we don't need the whole component file.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are returning a function back to order that is never being invoked, i think you are actually looking to invoke the individual item sorting function in `get_sorting()`.

so, reduce could look like

```
const get_sorting = (sort_dir, sort_by) => (
   (sort_dir === "desc" ? 1 : -1) * this.sort_desc(a, b, sort_by));
);
```

Comment: Let me try that out. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, my initial comment is only partially correct. You can return a fucntion from `get_sorting()` but you just need to invoke it, which you are never doing now. that is your problem. you are treating order as if it is as number when its a function that return a number;

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue had to do with the key value naming convention I had within my data array. The functions themselves worked fine. Thanks to everyone who responded.